# Qcow2 converted to vmdk show as spare and can't be snapshot

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, snapshot, vmware-vmdk, qcow2

As the title says, kvm disks that I converted and moved to ESXi are useless because I cannot use snapshots due to the fact that they are sparse disks.  Does anyone have a resolution for this issue? esxi 5 free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log onto ESXi server using SSH and convert with vmkfstools:

```
vmkfstools -i mysparedisk.vmdk -d eagerzeroedthick mythickdisk.vmdk
```

or alternatively...

```
vmkfstools -i mysparedisk.vmdk -d thin mythindisk.vmdk
```

Comment: What if it was set to split at 2GB so that I have multiple vmdk files for a single virtual disk?  Do I have to consolidate them first?  If so what is the recommended way over ssh in esxi free (5.1)?  If I don't, how do I do it without consolidating first?

Comment: vmkfstools does it all for you. Usually you have a disk1.vmdk file. This is a text file you can view in an editor. It references the real data files which are named like disk1-flat_<number>.vmdk or maybe disk1-s<number>.vmdk. Don't use vSphere's datastore browser as it'll hide stuff from you. Enable ssh support on your ESXi: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1017910